# Is using EAP-MD5 in strongSwan a security risk?

Tags: vpn, ipsec, strongswan, eap

Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Authentication_Protocol#EAP-MD5):

> It offers minimal security; the MD5 hash function is vulnerable to dictionary attacks, and does not support key generation, which makes it unsuitable for use with dynamic WEP, or WPA/WPA2 enterprise

However, Wikipedia discusses EAP-MD5 in the context of wireless authentication. If I understand correctly this is not a security risk in strongSwan since the authentication between the client and the server is encrypted. I'm I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in the context of strongSwan, or more generally [IKEv2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Key_Exchange), the EAP messages are transmitted encrypted in the IKE_AUTH exchanges. Man-in-the-middle attacks are averted by first authenticating the server with certificates using standard IKEv2 authentication. The security considerations in the [IKEv2 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7296) actually say:

> An implementation using EAP MUST also use a public-key-based
> authentication of the server to the client before the EAP
> authentication begins...

That's the case unless an EAP method with mutual authentication (e.g. EAP-TLS, but not EAP-MD5) is used and the client supports [EAP-only authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5998).

If the EAP authentication is not terminated on the VPN server but e.g. a separate RADIUS server, one has to consider that the communication between these two is generally not encrypted. To not leak any information there it is also possible to use EAP-MD5 within other EAP methods (e.g. [EAP-TTLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Authentication_Protocol#EAP-TTLS) or [EAP-PEAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_Extensible_Authentication_Protocol)), which provide a TLS tunnel within which the EAP-MD5 messages are transported to the authentication server. This also allows the client to authenticate that server, which is not possible with EAP-MD5 alone, as it does not provide mutual authentication. Combining such tunneling EAP methods with simple user authentication is also quite common for the WiFi use case (e.g. EAP-PEAP/EAP-MSCHAPv2).

Comment: You mean in the context of strongSwan, `right=eap-md5` does not expose the possibility of a man-in-the-middle attack as long as `left=pubkey` is used, right? (Compared to using `eap-md5` on both sides, for example.) – This raises one question: who guarantees that the authentication of “left” comes before “right”?

Comment: EAP-MD5 on both sides is not possible as this EAP method does not provide mutual authentication (unlike e.g. EAP-TLS). Edited my answer to clarify that IKEv2 ensures the server is authenticated first.